# Cleaning Lady Snooping Around

Tags: security, discipline

Our company contracts cleaning services to a third party cleaning service.  Last night I walked into my CEO's offices and caught our cleaning person sitting behind his desk on his chair texting and writing stuff down. A little investigation revealed that the cleaning person was in their with the door closed for an hour and thirty four minutes.

This is not something we have been trained to handle.  I am afraid that I will get in trouble if I handle this wrong.  What is the best and safest way for me to handle this situation?

Comment: Are you responsible for this person? Are you her manager, or do you manage the contract with her company? If not, then report this to the person in charge and let them handle it.

Comment: What happened after you caught her in your CEO's chair?

Answer (score 26):

If she is an employee, *report her to her manager*, and also let your manager know too. ( This way your manager is prepared for any discussions that come of this )

If she is an employee of a company your organization hired, report her to **your** manager.  Your manager should know who is responsible for hiring contractors, and that person should deal with the company ( *who will deal with her* ).  If you have a security officer, they should be notified too.

In either case, be sure to **only report what you have seen** in a professional facts based approach.  Be careful not to embellish past what you actually witnessed.

Comment: id report it to who ever handles security or the CEO if your company is to small